# How to migrate kafka details to other server?

Tags: apache-kafka

How do I got all details of kafka server like kafka topic names, partitions, groups etc before shutting kafka server. And use this information to ready new kafka server ?

Is there any option for this type of backup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka uses zookeeper to store metadata.

If you want to get overview of all topics, partitions or consumer groups, you can collect from zookeeper shell.

Example : to collect the consumer groups, use `ls /consumers` as following:

```
kafka % bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<<  "ls /consumers"
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[console-consumer-66605, console-consumer-84350, console-consumer-9354, console-consumer-28182, console-consumer-61085, console-consumer-67016, console-consumer-81504, console-consumer-47711, console-consumer-87328, console-consumer-27998, console-consumer-73330, console-consumer-73529, console-consumer-17369, console-consumer-75626, console-consumer-6886, console-consumer-11693]
```

Similarly for collecting topic names, use :

```
ls /brokers/topics
```

For collecting number of partitions :

```
ls /brokers/topics/<topic name>/partitions
```

You can export these details for some file and use for next server